# Move elements independently js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate different arrows to point at the cursor, but I can't find a light-weight solution for that.

I'm using the code below, but it seems to be a bit heavy to the website. Is there a way to optimise the code?

Cheers!
T

```
// the same as yours.
  function rotateOnMouse(e, pw) {
      var offset = pw.offset();
      var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
      var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
      var mouse_x = e.pageX;
      var mouse_y = e.pageY;
      var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
      var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1);
      $(pw).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  }

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD1'));
    });
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD2'));
    });
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD3'));
    });
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD4'));
    });
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD5'));
    });
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD6'));
    });


  });
```

http://codepen.io/thalesribeiro/pen/egVgpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few ideas that could help with the performance:

- use requestAnimationFrame when changing the transforms
- store the arrow nodes in a variable so the browser doesn't have to query them each mouse move, this will give you a big performance boost
- you are adding multiple event listeners, the same can be achieved with only one
- bind() is deprecated use on()

```js
var arrow1 = $('#arrowD1');
var arrow2 = $('#arrowD2');
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    rotateOnMouse(e, arrow1);
    rotateOnMouse(e, arrow2);
);
```

Did not test the code but it should give you an idea how it should look like.

**Edit:**

**Codepen with my suggestions: [codepen](http://codepen.io/mateop/pen/OWZpKV)**

Comment: hmm, it hasn't worked for me. Would you be able to show me and example on how it applies with the rest of the code?

Comment: I edited your codepen with my suggestions, added link to answer. Also if you want to further improve performance i suggest using a passive event listener which jquery does not support yet

Comment: How would it work if i wanted to call all the elements with the same class ? for instance .arrows and then i wouldnt have to call the same function for each arrow ?

Comment: If you do it that way you would still have to iterate over every arrow to calculate the rotation individually

Comment: Do you have an example on how I would do that?